# I am having problems with CSS on one of my pages, the page wrap appears to jump to the left slightly

Tags: css, html, tags

I have uploaded the website to the internet so you can see what i mean, if you click on the My CV link you will notice that the pagewrap div jumps to the left slightly.

http://users.aber.ac.uk/bes16/cs15020/

Many thanks!

Comment: That is because the scrollbar gets active. You can solve that with CSS and make the scrollbar consistent.
CSS rule: `body{overflow-y:scroll;}`

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the vertical scroll that's added after you visit the link, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer. The content of that page is longer, so the scrollbar on the right side jumps in, taking some space. So the content jumps left.